# Can a Mac Mini use a MacBook Air CD SuperDrive?

Tags: macos, mac-mini, optical-drive

Will a MacBook Air SuperDrive work with a new Mac mini?

The Apple [website](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MC684ZM/A) says it will work with Mac Mini on Snow Leopard server. No mention of New mac mini and OSX Lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if it doesn't have a built in optical drive. I think the limitation is built into the drive not the OS and as far as my searches have discovered can only be subverted by hardware hacks of the drive.

It's a bummer as it is is a neat little drive and Apple built-in slot loading drives are not that reliable (4 out of 5 of mine have failed over nearly a decade.) On the other hand there are a lot of cheap and ugly 3rd party alternatives which work fine.